# Reverse Engineering question - .NET packet capture

Tags: .net, reverse-engineering

I am working with someone who is interested in integrating a web application with a proprietary ERP client/server system. I am trying to figure out a way to reverse engineer the API calls to the server and duplicate it for the limited number of functions that I need to make the integration work.

I used wireshark to capture some network traffic from the client side. As a PHP/Java programmer, I am not very familiar with the .NET world, so I was hoping someone here could look at the TCP stream below and point me in the right direction. Is it possible, looking at the traffic, to tell what kind of .NET client to use to communicate with this server?

```
.NET.............."...tcp://XXXXXXXX:nnnn/Transporter.rem........application/octet-stream..........................GetMail.mDTA.Connectivity.ITransporter, DTA.Connectivity, Version=1.0.4098.30211, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null....................System.Guid....._a._b._c._d._e._f._g._h._i._j._k........................../.1D.).`..k..

.NET.......................................................System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[[DTA.Connectivity.Messaging.Message, DTA.Connectivity, Version=1.0.4098.30211, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].....items...System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[DTA.Connectivity.Messaging.Message, DTA.Connectivity, Version=1.0.4098.30211, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]..........NDTA.Connectivity, Version=1.0.4098.30211, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.......System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[DTA.Connectivity.Messaging.Message, DTA.Connectivity, Version=1.0.4098.30211, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]....._items._size._version...$DTA.Connectivity.Messaging.Message[].................................."DTA.Connectivity.Messaging.Message.....

.NET......D......."...tcp://XXXXXXXX:nnnn/Transporter.rem........application/octet-stream..........................SubmitOperation.mDTA.Connectivity.ITransporter, DTA.Connectivity, Version=1.0.4098.30211, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null........................NDTA.Connectivity, Version=1.0.4098.30211, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.....0DTA.Connectivity.Operations.DataManagerOperation....._Type_SqlStatement._SplitAtSemicolon
```

Comment: hmmm proprietary ERP, reverse engineering; Either you are dead in the water because the interface will change, or it won't and you're still in a dark place (because your ERP will quickly become obsolete); Could you not play the game above the sheets and contact the vendor... I know I know, silly naive thing to say

Comment: Your points are well taken. We have contacted the vendor, but they want to charge an outrageous sum to build a web connector themselves. What we want to do is too simple for a lot of expense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's .net remoting by the looks of things. This consists of serializing objects and passing them down the wire.

If the binaries for the application are available you may be able to add them as references to your solution so that you can use the same objects and intercept some of the packets. You may have to check that you're not violating any license requirements with that though.

Comment: agreed; looks like simple .NET remoting over standard TCP channels (unencrypted LOL) and BinaryFormatter serialization

Comment: Thank you very much for the bump in the right direction. I did some searches on .net remoting. Looks like unless I am able to recreate the objects to unserialize them, my idea is sunk. I was hoping to be able to do some simple RPC calls or something. Looks like .net remoting is obsolete as well, which goes to sehe's comment.